# Why doesn't my in app billing with remove ads feature work?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, admob, in-app-billing

I am trying to make an app that disables ads when the user makes a purchase. However, the ads don't even show when the app starts up currently.

If I put this in the `onCreate` method the ads will just load up when next the user starts up the app. (the ads go away when the user clicks on the **Remove ads** button though.)

`mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
                adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);`

**This is my `MainActivity.class`**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
IabHelper mHelper;
AdView mAdView;
MenuItem menuItem2;
AdRequest adRequest;
NavigationView nvDrawer;
DrawerLayout mDrawer;
RelativeLayout myView;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
AppBarLayout secondview;
SharedPreferences prefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener;
CoordinatorLayout container;

private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
public static final String TAG =
        "iboche.time.google.com.ibche.inappbilling";
static final String ITEM_SKU = "remove_ads";
final String mIsPremium = "purchased";

    @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String base64EncodedPublicKey =
            "MY PUBLIC KEY";

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
    menuItem2 = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.nav_second_fragment);
    nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
    adscontainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container2);
    mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    queryPurchasedItems();

    if(prefs.getBoolean(mIsPremium, false)){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"no premium",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
    else if(prefs.getBoolean(mIsPremium,true)) {
    mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"premium",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
    drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();
    mDrawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    mHelper.startSetup(new
                               IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                                   public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                                       if (!result.isSuccess()) {

                                           mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);
                                           Log.d(TAG, "Failed:");
                                       } else if (result.isSuccess()){

                                           Log.d(TAG, "OK");
                                       }
                                   }
                               });

}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mReceivedInventoryListener
        = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                                         Inventory inventory) {

        if (result.isFailure()) {
            // Handle failure


        }
        else {


            mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(ITEM_SKU),
                    mConsumeFinishedListener);
                              editor = prefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("purchased", mIsPremium);
                    editor.putBoolean(mIsPremium, true);
                    editor.commit();

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"premium", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }



    }
};
public void consumeItem() {
    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mReceivedInventoryListener);

}


@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
    return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
}
private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                    selectDrawerItem1(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });}

public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {

    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, ITEM_SKU, 0,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, "GENERIC TOKEN");

    mDrawer.closeDrawers();

    //if (mIsPremium){

    menuItem.setTitle("Purchased");
    mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
public void selectDrawerItem1(MenuItem menuItem) {

    mDrawer.closeDrawers();
}






@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent data)
{
    if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode,
            resultCode, data)) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
}
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {

    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result,
                                      Purchase purchase)
    {
        if (result.isFailure()) {

            if (result.getResponse() == IabHelper.BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED) {



                return;
            }
            // Handle error

        }
        else if(purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {

            editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("purchased", mIsPremium);
            editor.putBoolean(mIsPremium, true);
            editor.commit();
            consumeItem();
        }
    }


};

IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener =
        new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase,
                                          IabResult result) {

                if (result.isSuccess()) {


                } else {
                    // handle error

                }
            }
        };
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();

    mHelper = null;

        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to have a shared pref for the event of the iap to remove adds and then change it when the user does the iap .... then check for it at onCreate if ads are disabled and accordingly set `Visibilty = "GONE"` for the add container in layout in accordance to the shared pref .

try to call your SharedPreference just once, and then use editor to commit your data:

```
            SharedPreference SP;
            SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            editor = SP.edit();

            //...
                editor.putString("abc", udata);
                editor.commit();
            //...
                editor.putStringSet("si",ssetdata)
                editor.commit();
```

This is for the onCreate

```
    if(prefs.getBoolean("purchased", false)) {
mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
}
else if(prefs.getBoolean("purchased", true)){
 mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
...}
```

Read more on shared pref [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: I will take a look at that link soon, but doesn't the `onQueryInventoryFinished` check that the item has been purchased? So why does putting `mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)` in this method like I have done not work?

Comment: why check for the iap every time? just use shared pref to store the value once and you are good to go..

Comment: I just implemented it but it still doesn't work. The ads still come up when the app is started again and they disappear when the "Purchase" button is pressed.

Comment: wait i am looking into it.. are you checking for the iap onCreate ? and have you commited the shared pref change that you made?

Comment: This is in my **onCreate :**


`AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        if(prefs.getBoolean("purchased", false)) mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(prefs.getBoolean("purchased", true)) mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLM = new LinearLayoutManager(this);`

Comment: This is in my **onQueryInventoryFinished:**

`SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("purchased", inventory.hasPurchase(ITEM_SKU) );
                editor.apply();`

Comment: Correct way   if(prefs.getBoolean("purchased", false)) {mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE); }else if(prefs.getBoolean("purchased", true)){ mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);....

Comment: See my updates to the question. I don't believe the boolean is affected by my commits? Currently none of the toasts are showing.